# Generate x amount of points between two points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a line in the following way:

```
public class MyLineRenderer : MonoBehaviour {
LineRenderer lineRenderer;

public Vector3 p0, p1;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
   lineRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
   lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;

   lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, p0);
   lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, p1);

    }
}
```

How can I find, for example, 10 points on the line that are equally spaced from end to the other?

Comment: You have position A and B and what to find 10 equally spaced position between those two positions?

Comment: @Programmer Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) to generate a point between two points. Passing `0.5` to its `t` parameter will make it give you the **middle** position between PositionA and PositionB.

To generate *multiple* points between two points, you just have to use  `Vector3.Lerp` in loop.

Here is a function to do this:

```
void generatePoints(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Vector3[] result, int chunkAmount)
{
    //divider must be between 0 and 1
    float divider = 1f / chunkAmount;
    float linear = 0f;

    if (chunkAmount == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("chunkAmount Distance must be > 0 instead of " + chunkAmount);
        return;
    }

    if (chunkAmount == 1)
    {
        result[0] = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, 0.5f); //Return half/middle point
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < chunkAmount; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            linear = divider / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            linear += divider; //Add the divider to it to get the next distance
        }
        // Debug.Log("Loop " + i + ", is " + linear);
        result[i] = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, linear);
    }
}
```

**USAGE**:

```
//The two positions to generate point between
Vector3 positionA = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
Vector3 positionB = new Vector3(254, 210, 50);

//The number of points to generate
const int pointsCount = 10;
//Where to store those number of points
private Vector3[] pointsResult;

void Start()
{
    pointsResult = new Vector3[pointsCount];
    generatePoints(positionA, positionB, pointsResult, pointsCount);
}
```

The 10 different array points are now stored in the `pointsResult` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the first point of the line renderer in the array, you can do the following:

```
    int amnt = 10; // if you want 10 points
    Vector3[] points = new Vector3[amnt]; // your array of points

    for (int x = 0; x < amnt; x++)
    {
        points[x] = new Vector3((p1.x - p0.x) * x / (amnt-1), 
                                (p1.y - p0.y) * x / (amnt-1), 
                                (p1.z - p0.z) * x / (amnt-1)); // we divide by amnt - 1 here because we start at 0
    }
```